# dont need Css Hover effect on submenu items

Tags: html, css

I want hover functionality only on Main Menu Items: FIRMS, Projects and Contact

Currently when I hover on the rest of the body, it shows main menu items.
I want the hover effect only when the mouse is over Firms, Projects and Contact.

See my code below. I don't want a hover effect on sub-menu class items. What modifications are needed?

```css
.sub-menu{
   
}
/* Layout */

a {
 -moz-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
}


/* HEADER MENU */

#topmenu {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0 15px;
 position:relative;
 width:80%;
    float:right;
    height: auto;
    top: 20px;
    /* old previos top:100px;*/
}
#topmenu ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#topmenu ul li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 font-size:10px;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:auto;
 text-align:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 
}
#topmenu ul li:first-child {
 
}
#topmenu ul li a {
 margin-right: 60px;
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
}
#topmenu ul li a:hover {
 color:#999;
}
#topmenu ul li:hover > a {
 color:#999;
}



#topmenu ul li ul.sub-menu {
    height: 100px;
 float:left;
    height:auto;
 list-style:none;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
     width: 200px;
 opacity:0;
 visibility:visible;
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s 0.1s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
 -o-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
 transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
}
#topmenu ul li ul.sub-menu li {
 border:none;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 clear:both;
 margin-top:10px;
 padding:0;
    width: 100%;
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.1s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.1s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition:opacity 0.15s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
 transition:opacity 0.15s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
}

#topmenu ul li ul.sub-menu li a {

    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu {
 opacity:1;
 visibility:visible;
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li {
 margin-top:0;
 opacity:1;
    
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li a {
 color:black;
 -moz-transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
 
 -moz-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li:hover {
 

}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li:hover > a {
 color:#999;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #topmenu ul li .sub-menu li
    {
            line-height: 35px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    width: 230px;
    }
      #topmenu ul li .sub-menu li a
    {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 25px;
    float: left;
    }
     #topmenu ul li a{
        line-height: 0px;
     }
        
#topmenu ul {
overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
    position : inherit;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #topmenu ul li 
    {
        text-align:left;
        width:100%;
        float:left;
    }
 #topmenu ul li a{
            width: 100%;
            float:left
            
    }
    
    .header-wrapper .menu-nav {
    float: left;
    
    }
    .menu-mymenu-container
    {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="topmenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <div class="menu-mymenu-container">
            <ul class="menu-nav nav navbar-nav" id="topnav" style="display: block;">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-17 first-child" id="menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/architect/firm/">FIRM</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-118 first-child" id="menu-item-118"><a href="http://localhost/architect/firm/profilemm/">Profile</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117" id="menu-item-117"><a href="http://localhost/architect/philosophy/">Philosophy</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116" id="menu-item-116"><a href="http://localhost/architect/structure/">Structure</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115" id="menu-item-115"><a href="http://localhost/architect/services-sectors/">SERVICES + SECTORS</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-114" id="menu-item-114"><a href="http://localhost/architect/sustainability/">Sustainability</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113 last-child" id="menu-item-113"><a href="http://localhost/architect/client-list/">Client List</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-18" id="menu-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/architect/projects/">PROJECTS</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142 first-child" id="menu-item-142"><a href="http://localhost/architect/key-projects/">Key Projects</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-143" id="menu-item-143"><a href="http://localhost/architect/residential/">Residential</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140" id="menu-item-140"><a href="http://localhost/architect/commercial/">Commercial</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139" id="menu-item-139"><a href="http://localhost/architect/mixed-use/">Mixed Use</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type <menu-item>    </menu-item>-object-page menu-item-138" id="menu-item-138"><a href="http://localhost/architect/education/">Education</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137" id="menu-item-137"><a href="http://localhost/architect/hospitality/">Hospitality</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136" id="menu-item-136"><a href="http://localhost/architect/retail/">Retail</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135" id="menu-item-135"><a href="http://localhost/architect/masterplanning/">Masterplanning</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141 last-child" id="menu-item-141"><a href="http://localhost/architect/projects/past-highlights/">Past Highlights</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-19 last-child" id="menu-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/architect/contact/">CONTACT</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-133 first-child" id="menu-item-133"><a href="http://localhost/architect/general-information/">General Information</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-134 last-child" id="menu-item-134"><a href="http://localhost/architect/careers/">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>                
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JeZap/380/

Comment: I am not understanding what exactly you want in title you don't want here you want.

Comment: i want hover on on  FIRM,PRoject and Contact but whene you scroll below This links , hover is applied to submenu items

Comment: check fiddle link plz

Comment: try to hover on rest of body

Comment: Flagging for: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: i understand what do you want. please try to comment hover css one by one to diagnose such kind of problem

Comment: trying .. will be back soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this fiddle link and update your code.

jsfiddle.net/JeZap/385/

```css
.sub-menu{
   
}
/* Layout */

a {
 -moz-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
}


/* HEADER MENU */

#topmenu {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0 15px;
 position:relative;
 width:80%;
    float:right;
    height: auto;
    top: 20px;
    /* old previos top:100px;*/
}
#topmenu ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#topmenu ul li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 font-size:10px;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:auto;
 text-align:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 
}
#topmenu ul li:first-child {
 
}
#topmenu ul li a {
 margin-right: 60px;
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
}


#topmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
 color:#999;
}



#topmenu ul li ul.sub-menu {
    height: 100px;
 float:left;
    height:auto;
 list-style:none;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: white;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
     width: 200px;
 opacity:0;
 visibility:hidden;
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s 0.1s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
 -o-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
 transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out, visibility 0.1s 0.1s linear;
}
#topmenu ul li ul.sub-menu li {
 border:none;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 clear:both;
 margin-top:10px;
 padding:0;
    width: 100%;
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.1s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.1s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition:opacity 0.15s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
 transition:opacity 0.15s 0.15s ease-out, margin 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
}

#topmenu ul li ul.sub-menu li a {

    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu {
 opacity:1;
 visibility:visible;
  
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li {
 margin-top:0;
 opacity:1;
    
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li a {
 color:black;
 -moz-transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.1s ease-out;
}
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
 
 -moz-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
}

#topmenu #topnav > li:hover > a {
 color:#999;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #topmenu ul li .sub-menu li
    {
            line-height: 35px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    width: 230px;
    }
      #topmenu ul li .sub-menu li a
    {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 25px;
    float: left;
    }
     #topmenu ul li a{
        line-height: 0px;
     }
        
#topmenu ul {
overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
    position : inherit;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #topmenu ul li 
    {
        text-align:left;
        width:100%;
        float:left;
    }
 #topmenu ul li a{
            width: 100%;
            float:left
            
    }
    
    .header-wrapper .menu-nav {
    float: left;
    
    }
    .menu-mymenu-container
    {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="topmenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <div class="menu-mymenu-container">
            <ul class="menu-nav nav navbar-nav" id="topnav" style="display: block;">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-17 first-child" id="menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/architect/firm/">FIRM</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-118 first-child" id="menu-item-118"><a href="http://localhost/architect/firm/profilemm/">Profile</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117" id="menu-item-117"><a href="http://localhost/architect/philosophy/">Philosophy</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116" id="menu-item-116"><a href="http://localhost/architect/structure/">Structure</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115" id="menu-item-115"><a href="http://localhost/architect/services-sectors/">SERVICES + SECTORS</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-114" id="menu-item-114"><a href="http://localhost/architect/sustainability/">Sustainability</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113 last-child" id="menu-item-113"><a href="http://localhost/architect/client-list/">Client List</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-18" id="menu-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/architect/projects/">PROJECTS</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-142 first-child" id="menu-item-142"><a href="http://localhost/architect/key-projects/">Key Projects</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-143" id="menu-item-143"><a href="http://localhost/architect/residential/">Residential</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140" id="menu-item-140"><a href="http://localhost/architect/commercial/">Commercial</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-139" id="menu-item-139"><a href="http://localhost/architect/mixed-use/">Mixed Use</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type <menu-item>    </menu-item>-object-page menu-item-138" id="menu-item-138"><a href="http://localhost/architect/education/">Education</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137" id="menu-item-137"><a href="http://localhost/architect/hospitality/">Hospitality</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136" id="menu-item-136"><a href="http://localhost/architect/retail/">Retail</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135" id="menu-item-135"><a href="http://localhost/architect/masterplanning/">Masterplanning</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141 last-child" id="menu-item-141"><a href="http://localhost/architect/projects/past-highlights/">Past Highlights</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-19 last-child" id="menu-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/architect/contact/">CONTACT</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-133 first-child" id="menu-item-133"><a href="http://localhost/architect/general-information/">General Information</a></li>
                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-134 last-child" id="menu-item-134"><a href="http://localhost/architect/careers/">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/JeZap/381/

When you have something like`#top-menu ul li:hover` you will be getting all `ul li` elements under `#top-menu`.

Using `#top-menu > ul > li:hover` will make sure only it's direct descendants will be affected by the rule.

Comment: What isn't working? In the fiddle, the hover effects are only affecting the parent menu items. What else were you looking for?

Comment: yes bro.. it is not working ... but i am trying again after clearing browser cache. let me see the effect.

Comment: have a look at this video. this is your fiddle output. same as mine fiddle output http://mctdemo.in/hover.swf

Answer (score 2):

add this css to your example:

```
.sub-menu
{
    display:none;
}
```

and replace following css

```
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

with this one

```
#topmenu #topnav li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: it is working fine but the only problem is "Menu effects such as ease-out.. not working any more" this is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JeZap/384/